# Basic array questions to answer

Tags: arrays

Make an array of the months. Access the 1st month. Access the last month. How do you get the length?

Make an ArrayList of CoffeeOrders. How do you access the 1st order? How do you add an order, how do you get how many orders are stored, etc

Comment: Have any work to show?

Comment: You cannot just dump in some questions and expect a solution. Questions should be one per post, and have enough effort that we're not doing all your homework

Comment: Relax. I have a test coming up and I'm just trying to understand the concepts. I am not trying to make anyone angry.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the coding language you are using an array can mean a couple of different things. At its most basic level an array is a list of information of the same type (integers, characters, whatever).
Most systems will use a 0-index array reference system. This means the "location" of the first piece of information in an array is at position 0 and the last piece is at the number of items 'n' minus 1.

If for example you make an array containing months, you may load the information however you like (alphabetical, numerically, whatever) and use the month's index to retrieve it.  Code below uses C# syntax, but most languages are very similar on this topic.  Very cursory research will help you find what you are looking for.

```
string[] monthsArray = new string[12];
//spend some time entering data into the array, either with a loop or some other method
monthsArray[0] = "January";

for (int i =0; i < monthsArray.Length; i++){
    someoutputobject = monthsArray[i];
}
```

this block of code demonstrates how to do just about everything you asked about.  The "for" loop will access each index of the array from 0-11 and send the data to some output object.

To add new data to the array, it's just the same as retrieving it:

```
monthsArray[i] = "Janutember";
```

this will set the 'i' position in the array to "Janutember".

Comment: Thanks! I am using Java